# Visual Studio 2015 Professional UWP creation issue

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp

I have installed a full version of `Visual Studio 2015 Professional` on `Windows 10`. I have installed `UWP` as well. When ever i create a `UWP` project, `visual studio` throws an error

```
"End of central directory record not found"
```

And throws lot of compilation errors for adding `mscorlib.dll`.

Stuck on this for a long time now. please suggest solutions if any one is facing the same issue

Comment: Somewhere ... there's a corrupt Zip file in the installation that apparently is required. The error is usually associated with a malformed zip file. (And the file may have an extension other than `zip`). Have you tried an uninstall/reinstall?

Comment: yeah. I was assuming the same. uninstall and reinstall dint help. Still facing the same issue. Could it be due to slow network ?I mean the files could have got corrupted. The exact problem is with the Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 5.0.0 which is not getting extracted. Neither Visual Studio is able to do it nor the Nuget Package Manager.